# Execute Command prompt command from Excel Spread Sheet

Tags: python, excel, vba, cmd

Okay so this might be a little bit different. First I will start by stating my personal case the i will broaden it. I am Using robot framework with python. So i have a text file that has all the commands i want it to do. So to run the command, I go to my CMD and type               " pybot NameOfFile.txt " that runs the robot framework commands. I am going to make a presentation of this. So i want to run the command by just clicking a "Command button" on the developer tools in Excel. Or any other way really. So far, no luck. Please if anyone can help me out that would be fantastic.

Comment: Are you asking how to execute "pybot file.txt" with a single click?

Comment: @ScottLawson Yes, preferebly in Excel. Usually you would execute the file in CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Shell ("cmd /C ""start pybot NameOfFile.txt""")
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: omg dude that is exactly what i need! but the CMD has to be started from a specific file. i tried this --     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Shell ("cmd /C:\Users\cwr.Diego.Gomez\Desktop\main_test_suite\myTests ""start pybot Diego.txt""")
End Sub

Comment: when i run it nothin happens

Comment: Nothing happens? Hm. What happens if you try `Shell ("cmd /K ""start pybot --version""")`? Note the /K, so the CMD remains open.

Comment: the original one you put works like a charm. Its just that when I try to put my own path that i want the cmd to open in --as i showed above -- nothig happens. so i was wondering if there is a specific way t file a specific path

Comment: `Shell ("cmd /C ""cd ""P:\Test\"" && start pybot ""P:Neu Textdokument.txt""""")` warrantless without legal ;-) In cd-part the full path, in start part only the drive.

Comment: You sir, are a God among men. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `Shell(commandline)` in VBA. Be aware that it will require full path and filename for your `pybot` executable and the argument (txt file). See [How can I execute a shell command using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290365/how-can-i-execute-a-shell-command-using-vba)

A possible call would look like  `Shell(chr(34) & "c:\path\to\py\pybot.exe" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & "c:\file name with spaces.txt" & chr(34))`.

Comment: Its probably alot to ask, but can you try to give me a spcific example?

Comment: How would i add the filename from my pybot in the command line?

Comment: Did you check the link (answer two) for an example? Would be something like `Shell(chr(34) & "c:\path\to\py\pybot.exe" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & "c:\file name with spaces.txt" & chr(34))`.

Comment: Public Sub Display_CMD()
Shell(C:\Users\cwr.Diego.Gomez\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7.exe" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & "c:\Diego.txt" & chr(34))
End Sub

Comment: Missing `"` (and chr(34)) at the start of the command. Anyway, I doubt that this is the correct path to your python exe.

Comment: Shell (Chr(34) & "C:\Python27.exe" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & "C:\Users\cwr.Diego.Gomez\Desktop\main_test_suite\myTests\Diego.txt" & Chr(34))  ... sould be working better but now its telling me chr(34) *the first one* is an invalid outside procedure