# Start application from VBA shell

Tags: excel, vba, shell

In excel I'm trying to insert a button to parse the contents of selected cells to a new email. Since I use Mozilla Thunderbird, I have to parse through Shell.
My code so far:

```
    Dim dr As String
    If dir("C:\Program Files (x64)", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        dr = "C:\Program Files (x86)"
    Else
        dr = "C:\Program Files"
    End If
    dr = dr & "\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"

    Dim args As String
    args = "to='" & MailTo & "',cc='" & MailCC & "',bcc='" & MailBCC & "'"
    args = args & ",subject='" & MailSubject & "',body='" & strbody & "'"
    If MailBijlage <> "" Then args = args & ",attachment='" & TempFilePath & TempFileName & ".pdf"

    Dim Command As String

    Command = "cmd.exe /S /K " & """" & dr & """" & " -compose " & """" & args & """"

    conf = MsgBox(Command, vbOKCancel, "Confirm command")

    If conf = vbOK Then
        Shell (Command)
        MsgBox "Email sent.", , "Info"
    ElseIf conf = vbCancel Then
        MsgBox "Canceled.", , "Info"
    End If
```

Creating the Command is handled well, but Shell won't start Thunderbird. It just says:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operatable program or batch file.

I don't know what's wrong, the message box showing the code clearly shows the double quotes around the path.

Thanks in advance.

==EDIT==

Trying to get it working using a batch file now (as suggested by S O)...
I opened a bat file (which is created) and let VBA output commands to the bat-file.
When I get to the point of the msgbox asking to send the mail, when I open the bat-file in notepad, it's empty. VBA calls the empty batch file and nothing happens (mail was not sent). When I reopen the file after the macro has ended, all output is in the batch file and when I run it, a mail is composed as it should.

```
        Open Environ("userprofile") & "\desktop\tbmail.bat" For Output As #1
    If dir("C:\Program Files (x64)", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Print #1, "cd ""%programfiles(x86)%"""
    Else
        Print #1, "cd ""%programfiles%"""
    End If
    Print #1, "cd ""Mozilla Thunderbird"""

        Print #1, "thunderbird.exe -compose """ & args & """"
    Close #1

    If conf = vbOK Then
        Call Shell(Environ("userprofile") & "\desktop\tbmail.bat")
        MsgBox "De mail is verstuurd.", , "Informatie"
    ElseIf conf = vbCancel Then
        MsgBox "Versturen geannuleerd.", , "Informatie"
    End If
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the data stored in the variable named "Command"? Also when you do Shell you don't need the CMD.EXE or do you? See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290365/how-can-i-execute-a-shell-command-using-vba

Comment: I did. The variable dr is created first and gives the absolute path to the Thunderbird application (thunderbird.exe) and args contains all arguments which need to be added to compose a mail from command line.
Not calling cmd.exe in Shell(), would it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cmd.exe` to just `CMD`

If it still isn't working you could try try:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run Command, 1, False
```

Change 1 to 0 if you want to hide the console,
Change False to True if you want the wait for user return in console.

Or you could so something like:

```
Open Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\test.bat" For Output As #1
Print #1, Command
Close #1
Shell Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\test.bat"
Kill Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\desktop\test.bat"
```

which is writing the command to a batch file and using the Shell command to call the batch file.

I generally prefer to use the `WScript.Shell` object because it allows for things like reading the StdOut to which is very useful.

Comment: cmd.exe or CMD doesn't matter, still the same error.
The CreateObject also gives the same error. It's as if the code passed to cmd ignores double quotes.